# MotionLayout does not pass nested scroll up to parent

Tags: android-motionlayout

I am using 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha5'.
I have a fragment using MotionLayout inside an activity that also carries a BottomNavigationView inside a CoordinatorLayout with a custom behaviour allowing to show and hide when the content is scrolled.
With all fragments, where there is no MotionLayout, this behaviour works perfectly. Only with the MotionLayout, which has a NestedScrollView as a child, and makes use of an onSwipe transition, this swipe seems to be consumed, and does not arrive at the activity's coordinator layout.
Is this a current limitation of how MotionLayout works, and is it possible to extend it to support my use case?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I did not find a solution, I had given up the experiments with MotionLayout.